# NoClassDefFoundError: scala/collection/StringOps

Tags: scala

I keep getting this exception
`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/collection/StringOps$` 
but I have `org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.13.6:jar` on my classpath. Do you know how to resolve this issue?

build.sbt

```
scalaVersion := "2.13.6"
libraryDependencies ++= Seq( "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.12" % "3.1.2")
```

Comment: You can't use a `2.12` binary with **Scala** `2.13` use **Scala** `2.12` and remove the suffix from the artifact and rather use `%%`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spark 3.1 is compatible with scala 2.12, so I needed to downgrade to `scalaVersion := 2.12`

Comment: I was having error with s3mock. I used version 2.13 and it worked.